# Another tkz-euclide issue

Tags: tkz-euclide

I feel very thankful for marmot for helping me with this problem, but I have another problem. It seems like tkz is actually very hard to understand. I have added the `\usetkzobj{all}` command and it does actually work, although as I get further in the paper [(tkz-euclide)](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf) it doesn't work anymore! Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5]\tkzGrid[sub]
\tkzDefPoint(1,2){A} \tkzDefPoint(3,4){B}
\tkzDefPoint(3,2){C} \tkzDefPoint(3,1){D}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B A,C A,D)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=red](A,B,C,D) \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,D)
\tkzFindSlope(A,B){SAB} \tkzFindSlope(A,C){SAC}\tkzFindSlope(A,D){SAD}
\tkzText[fill=Gold!50,draw=brown](2.5,0){La pente de (AB) est : \SAB}
\tkzText[fill=Gold!50,draw=brown](2.5,-.5){La pente de (AC) est : \SAC}
\tkzText[fill=Gold!50,draw=brown](2.5,-1){La pente de (AD) est : \SAD}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

```
See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.17 ...brown](2.5,0){La pente de (AB) est : \SAB}

? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image: Grid]

Comment: I used WinEdt for making this code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't shown the whole error message. It says

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Gold'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 ...own](2.5,-.5){La pente de (AC) est : \SAC}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit
```

The key part being the first line.

`xcolor` does have a lot of predefined colors, but they are not loaded by default. For `Gold`, you need to load `xcolor` with the `svgnames` option. Of course, you're not loading `xcolor` explicitly, that's done by TikZ, but you could do

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
```

which will pass `svgnames` to `xcolor` when it's loaded. With that modification your code runs without error.

Comment: Thanks! I really didn't know that xcolor didn't load all the colors!